# Tensorflow seq2seq tutorial: NoneType object has no attribute 'update'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to follow the tensorflow tutorial from https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/seq2seq.

The data seems to load fine but when I initialize the model I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/<username>/PycharmProjects/tensorflow_chatbot/execute.py", line 334, in <module>
    train()
  File "/Users/<username>/PycharmProjects/tensorflow_chatbot/execute.py", line 151, in train
    model = create_model(sess, False)
  File "/Users/<username>/PycharmProjects/tensorflow_chatbot/execute.py", line 113, in create_model
    forward_only=forward_only)
  File "/Users/<username>/PycharmProjects/tensorflow_chatbot/seq2seq_model_tf.py", line 181, in __init__
    softmax_loss_function=softmax_loss_function)
  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_source_gpu/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/legacy_seq2seq/python/ops/seq2seq.py", line 1206, in model_with_buckets
    decoder_inputs[:bucket[1]])
  File "/Users/<username>/PycharmProjects/tensorflow_chatbot/seq2seq_model_tf.py", line 180, in <lambda>
    lambda x, y: seq2seq_f(x, y, False),
  File "/Users/<username>/PycharmProjects/tensorflow_chatbot/seq2seq_model_tf.py", line 144, in seq2seq_f
    dtype=dtype)
  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_source_gpu/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/legacy_seq2seq/python/ops/seq2seq.py", line 848, in embedding_attention_seq2seq
    encoder_cell = copy.deepcopy(cell)
  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_source_gpu/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 174, in deepcopy
    y = copier(memo)
  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_source_gpu/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 476, in __deepcopy__
    setattr(result, k, copy.deepcopy(v, memo))
  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_source_gpu/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 163, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_source_gpu/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 230, in _deepcopy_list
    y.append(deepcopy(a, memo))
  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_source_gpu/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 190, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_source_gpu/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 334, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_source_gpu/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 163, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_source_gpu/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 257, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_source_gpu/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 190, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_source_gpu/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 334, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_source_gpu/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 163, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_source_gpu/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 257, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_source_gpu/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 190, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_source_gpu/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 334, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_source_gpu/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 163, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_source_gpu/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 257, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_source_gpu/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 190, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_source_gpu/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 334, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_source_gpu/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 163, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_source_gpu/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 257, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_source_gpu/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 163, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_source_gpu/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 257, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_source_gpu/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 163, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_source_gpu/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 230, in _deepcopy_list
    y.append(deepcopy(a, memo))
  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_source_gpu/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 190, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_source_gpu/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 334, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_source_gpu/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 163, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_source_gpu/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 257, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_source_gpu/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 190, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_source_gpu/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 334, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_source_gpu/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 163, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_source_gpu/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 257, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_source_gpu/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 190, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_source_gpu/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 334, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_source_gpu/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 163, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_source_gpu/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 257, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_source_gpu/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 163, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_source_gpu/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 230, in _deepcopy_list
    y.append(deepcopy(a, memo))
  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_source_gpu/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 163, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_source_gpu/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 237, in _deepcopy_tuple
    y.append(deepcopy(a, memo))
  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_source_gpu/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 163, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_source_gpu/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 257, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_source_gpu/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 190, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_source_gpu/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 334, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_source_gpu/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 163, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_source_gpu/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 257, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_source_gpu/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 190, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "/Users/<username>/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_source_gpu/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 343, in _reconstruct
    y.__dict__.update(state)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update'
```

If I change the `_buckets` variable in `translate.py` to only have 1 tuple (it doesn't matter which one), there is no issue but training does not work very well.  Any more than 1 tuple causes this error.  No changes have been made to the files found on github at https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/tutorials/rnn/translate other than changing the file names for my local project.

The beginning of the `__init__` function leading up to the area looks like:

```
def __init__(self,
             source_vocab_size,
             target_vocab_size,
             buckets,
             size,
             num_layers,
             max_gradient_norm,
             batch_size,
             learning_rate,
             learning_rate_decay_factor,
             use_lstm=False,
             num_samples=512,
             forward_only=False,
             dtype=tf.float32):
    """Create the model.

Args:
  source_vocab_size: size of the source vocabulary.
  target_vocab_size: size of the target vocabulary.
  buckets: a list of pairs (I, O), where I specifies maximum input length
    that will be processed in that bucket, and O specifies maximum output
    length. Training instances that have inputs longer than I or outputs
    longer than O will be pushed to the next bucket and padded accordingly.
    We assume that the list is sorted, e.g., [(2, 4), (8, 16)].
  size: number of units in each layer of the model.
  num_layers: number of layers in the model.
  max_gradient_norm: gradients will be clipped to maximally this norm.
  batch_size: the size of the batches used during training;
    the model construction is independent of batch_size, so it can be
    changed after initialization if this is convenient, e.g., for decoding.
  learning_rate: learning rate to start with.
  learning_rate_decay_factor: decay learning rate by this much when needed.
  use_lstm: if true, we use LSTM cells instead of GRU cells.
  num_samples: number of samples for sampled softmax.
  forward_only: if set, we do not construct the backward pass in the model.
  dtype: the data type to use to store internal variables.
"""
    self.source_vocab_size = source_vocab_size
    self.target_vocab_size = target_vocab_size
    self.buckets = buckets
    self.batch_size = batch_size
    self.learning_rate = tf.Variable(
        float(learning_rate), trainable=False, dtype=dtype)
    self.learning_rate_decay_op = self.learning_rate.assign(
        self.learning_rate * learning_rate_decay_factor)
    self.global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)

    # If we use sampled softmax, we need an output projection.
    output_projection = None
    softmax_loss_function = None
    # Sampled softmax only makes sense if we sample less than vocabulary size.
    if 0 < num_samples < self.target_vocab_size:
        w_t = tf.get_variable("proj_w", [self.target_vocab_size, size], dtype=dtype)
        w = tf.transpose(w_t)
        b = tf.get_variable("proj_b", [self.target_vocab_size], dtype=dtype)
        output_projection = (w, b)

        def sampled_loss(labels, logits):
            labels = tf.reshape(labels, [-1, 1])
            # We need to compute the sampled_softmax_loss using 32bit floats to
            # avoid numerical instabilities.
            local_w_t = tf.cast(w_t, tf.float32)
            local_b = tf.cast(b, tf.float32)
            local_inputs = tf.cast(logits, tf.float32)
            return tf.cast(
                tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(
                    weights=local_w_t,
                    biases=local_b,
                    labels=labels,
                    inputs=local_inputs,
                    num_sampled=num_samples,
                    num_classes=self.target_vocab_size),
                dtype)

        softmax_loss_function = sampled_loss

    # Create the internal multi-layer cell for our RNN.
    def single_cell():
        return tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell(size)

    if use_lstm:
        def single_cell():
            return tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(size)
    cell = single_cell()
    if num_layers > 1:
        cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([single_cell() for _ in range(num_layers)])

    # The seq2seq function: we use embedding for the input and attention.
    def seq2seq_f(encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs, do_decode):
        return tf.contrib.legacy_seq2seq.embedding_attention_seq2seq(
            encoder_inputs,
            decoder_inputs,
            cell,
            num_encoder_symbols=source_vocab_size,
            num_decoder_symbols=target_vocab_size,
            embedding_size=size,
            output_projection=output_projection,
            feed_previous=do_decode,
            dtype=dtype)

    # Feeds for inputs.
    self.encoder_inputs = []
    self.decoder_inputs = []
    self.target_weights = []
    for i in xrange(buckets[-1][0]):  # Last bucket is the biggest one.
        self.encoder_inputs.append(tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None],
                                                  name="encoder{0}".format(i)))
    for i in xrange(buckets[-1][1] + 1):
        self.decoder_inputs.append(tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None],
                                                  name="decoder{0}".format(i)))
        self.target_weights.append(tf.placeholder(dtype, shape=[None],
                                                  name="weight{0}".format(i)))

    # Our targets are decoder inputs shifted by one.
    targets = [self.decoder_inputs[i + 1]
               for i in xrange(len(self.decoder_inputs) - 1)]

    # Training outputs and losses.
    if forward_only:
        self.outputs, self.losses = tf.contrib.legacy_seq2seq.model_with_buckets(
            self.encoder_inputs, self.decoder_inputs, targets,
            self.target_weights, buckets, lambda x, y: seq2seq_f(x, y, True),
            softmax_loss_function=softmax_loss_function)
        # If we use output projection, we need to project outputs for decoding.
        if output_projection is not None:
            for b in xrange(len(buckets)):
                self.outputs[b] = [
                    tf.matmul(output, output_projection[0]) + output_projection[1]
                    for output in self.outputs[b]
                ]
    else:
        self.outputs, self.losses = tf.contrib.legacy_seq2seq.model_with_buckets(
            self.encoder_inputs, self.decoder_inputs, targets,
            self.target_weights, buckets,
            lambda x, y: seq2seq_f(x, y, False),
            softmax_loss_function=softmax_loss_function) # this is where the error occurrs
```

What do I need to change to get this to work?  Using tensorflow version 1.2

UPDATE:  This has been tested with both tensorflow built from source and built from the Pip package on Mac OSX Sierra and the same issue is occurring

Comment: Could you add the code which leads to this error?

Comment: Not sure if you saw the edit before you posted that but it is literally the code from the github repo without modification.

Comment: Added the specific function for clarity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as I have already commented [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8191#issuecomment-311003867) the model are you trying to implement is deprecated. If you want to make it working check the code I've pasted in the issue. 
Starting from tensorflow 1.1 and 1.2 you have the functions for dynamic decode like `tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn`. It allows you to take into account dynamic sized sequences for free.

I'm creating some examples and I'll post you a working example with the new api.

Comment: Thank you!  I couldn't get the code to work by just importing from `legacy_seq2seq` (pulled and rebuilt from master an hour ago) so I just copied the function and then it worked.  If you could post the link to the new API here when you are done that would be awesome.

Comment: I also made an issue on github (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1733) which I'll update with this answer

Comment: Finally Google releases an update tutorial https://github.com/tensorflow/nmt . It covers all the stuff I'd like to write for an intro tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I think the library you are using must have some requirements that are not properly installed. check them with accurate version of libraries and it might work.